# Cloning a github repo using REST

Tags: git, rest, github, github-api

I have a requirement to clone a github repository using REST calls from a client. I only seem to find a REST API to create a new repository using a POST call, but there doesn't seem to be the possibility to provide a source repository to clone it.

Is there a way to do it via normal HTTPS calls?

To add some infos: I have a remote git repository with a lot of content in it and the requirement is to create a remote copy of it (clone it) from a client using HTTPS. Later the client will perform operations on the cloned repository only and at some point there needs to be a push from the cloned git to the original one.

Answer (score 0):

You could create it from a [template](https://github.blog/2019-06-06-generate-new-repositories-with-repository-templates/) which would be your source repo: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-using-a-template

Then from there on, just create normal commits from the cloned repo to the original one: http://www.levibotelho.com/development/commit-a-file-with-the-github-api/

Answer (score 0):

`npm i simple-git`

```js
    const USER = 'something';
    const PASS = 'somewhere';
    const REPO = 'github.com/username/private-repo';

    const git = require('simple-git');
    const remote = `https://${USER}:${PASS}@${REPO}`;

    git().silent(true)
      .clone(remote)
      .then(() => console.log('finished'))
      .catch((err) => console.error('failed: ', err));
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.